# How to set permission on a file of sdcard programmatically in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to set read only permission on a video file which is on the sdcard so that it cannot be deleted. Is it possible in android? If so, How?

Answer (score 1):

Have a `File` object point to the file...

And `setReadOnly()` function should mark the file as Readonly.

Note: It won't make it "undeletable". Someone can remove the readonly flag and delete it just as easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [`chmod`](http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/14-tipstricks/570-using-chmod-in-android), but it's not part of the public api, so use with extreme caution.

Comment: Thanks fredley for your valuable response but this not woks for me, I am giving chmod 400 permission but anyuser can delete the same from Android device. Please suggest if I am doing wrong.

Comment: Unless the device is rooted, it's impossible to make a file that the user cannot delete, since your app runs as the user.